Upgrade to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.2.5, which uses Spring 6 cannot be lanched
I am upgrading an app from an older version of Spring (4) to Spring 6 and Spring Boot from 2.* to 3.2.5. It compiles, but I cannot run it due to the following stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: UUID
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
    // Additional stack trace
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UUID
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.registerJpaGenerators(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar!/:6.4.4]
    // Additional stack trace

Below is my pom.xml file content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>bioMedical</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bioMedical</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
</project>



The only class where UUID is used is in the RegisterController.
Here's the relevant part of that class:
package com.spring.bioMedical.Controller;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import com.nulabinc.zxcvbn.Strength;
import com.nulabinc.zxcvbn.Zxcvbn;
import com.spring.bioMedical.entity.User;
import com.spring.bioMedical.service.EmailService;
import com.spring.bioMedical.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class RegisterController {
    // Methods with @RequestMapping annotations
}

Can anyone help identify, why this error occurs and how to fix it?

I ended up finding the issue, jakarta.persistence-api 3.0.0 does not appear to have a replacement for javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory. so I just replace it with jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0, which contains jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.

How you fix this issue, i saw both the lib (version) contain the class you mentioned jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Another reason for this issue is the jakarta.jakartaee-api-9.0.0.jar dependency.
In my case, I am using Spring Boot 3.3.3, which includes jakarta.jakartaee-api-9.0.0.jar directly. This setup works perfectly fine on a standalone or local machine, but it fails during cloud deployment.
To fix this issue, I had to remove the jakarta.jakartaee-api-9.0.0.jar dependency from my pom.xml.
